# SKLightNode: Changing alpha of ambientColor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklightnode

Is there a way to change the alpha value of an `SKLightNodes` `ambientColor` so that e.g. their background can be seen even if the lightNode is on the other side of the screen?

```
//Add LightNode
let lightNode = SKLightNode()
lightNode.ambientColor = UIColor.blackColor()
lightNode.lightColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
lightNode.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
lightNode.categoryBitMask = LightCategory.Light1.rawValue
lightNode.enabled = true
lightNode.falloff = 0.05
self.addChild(lightNode)

//Sprite
sprite.lightingBitMask = LightCategory.Light1.rawValue
```

Answer (score 1):

It says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLightNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKLightNode/ambientColor) in the SKLightNode Class Reference that, "The alpha value of the color is ignored." If you want things on the other end of the screen to be visible, you should change the falloff.